# General Topology: basic closing properties in induced topology

Tags: general-topology

If $\tau_{X}$ is the topology in $X$ then the subspace topology in any $Y\subset X$ is the induced topology $\tau_{Y}=\{T\cap Y:T\in \tau_{X}\}$. This follows that the closed in $Y$ are $\overline{\tau_Y}=\{Y\backslash (T\cap Y):T\in \tau_{X}\}$. So if $Z\subset Y\subset X$ then $Cl_{Y}(Z)=Y\cap Cl_{X}(Z)$.
So if $Z=Cl_{Y}(Z)$ and $Y=Cl_{X}(Y)$ then:

$$Z=Cl_{Y}(Z)=Y\cap Cl_{X}(Z)=Cl_{X}(Y)\cap Cl_{X}(Z)=Cl_{X}(Z)$$.

I know that as $ Y $ is closed then $Cl_{X}(Y)=Y$. But I couldn't understand why this equality is worth here:
$$Cl_{X}(Y)\cap Cl_{X}(Z)=Cl_{X}(Z)$$

I would like to understand the intuitive notion of this equality.

Comment: *How* do you know that $Y$ is closed? Where is that assumption?

Comment: @Milou, can you please accept the answers that have been useful to you? We see that you asked 18 questions without accepting any answer. This is definitely not polite and you should at least try to follow the rules of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Z\subset Y$, $Cl_X(Z)\subset Cl_X(Y)$, so $Cl_X(Y)\cap Cl_X(Z)=Cl_X(Z)$.